# Store special deals, like 3 for 2

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x

I have to apply two deals on the cart.

- Buy 3 (equal) items and pay for 2
- Buy 3 (in a set of items) and the cheapest is free

Items in cart:

```
----
|Car|
----
{'itemcode': 4, 'cost': 20.5, 'type': 'car', 'name': 'volvo'}
{'itemcode': 5, 'cost': 25, 'type': 'car', 'name': 'tesla'}
{'itemcode': 6, 'cost': 15, 'type': 'car', 'name': 'Ford'}
-----
|Tractor|
--------
{'itemcode': 7, 'cost': 10, 'type': 'tractor', 'name': 'mahindra'}
{'itemcode': 8, 'cost': 10, 'type': 'tractor', 'name': 'hmt'}
{'itemcode': 9, 'cost': 5, 'type': 'tractor', 'name': 'farmtrac'}
```

Below is the code I have written.

```py
def print_receipts(types):
    """Prints the receipts with deals applied.

    Args
        types (collection.defaultdict) : items purchased with cost.
    """
    print "\n\t-: Payment Receipt :-\n"
    grand_total = []
    new_total = 0
    deal_one_msg = ""
    types_two = copy.deepcopy(types)
    for item, costs in types.items():
        if len(costs) >= 3:
            saving = costs.pop(costs.index(min(costs)))
            total = sum(costs)
            grand_total.append(total)
            print u"\tSaving: \xa3{} on {}".format(saving, item)
            deal_one_msg = "Deal Buy 3 for price of 2: "
            print u"\tType: {} Total: \xa3{}".format(item, total)
        else:
            new_total -= min(costs) * -1
            new_total = new_total if len(costs) > 1 else costs[0]
            grand_total.append(new_total)
            print u"\tType-: {} Total: \xa3{}".format(item, new_total)
    print u"\t{}Grand Total: \xa3{}".format(deal_one_msg, sum(grand_total))
    sets_cost = []
    if len(types_two.items()) < 3:
        return
    deal_two = True
    deal_two_msg = "3 sets: "
    saved = 0
    for item, _costs in types_two.items():
        sets_cost.append(sum(_costs))
        if len(_costs) != 3:
            deal_two = False
    if deal_two:
        deal_two_msg = "Deal get 3rd set free: "
        saved = sets_cost.pop(sets_cost.index(min(sets_cost)))
    grand_total_sets = sum(sets_cost)
    if grand_total_sets > 0 and saved > 0:
        print u"\tSaved \xa3{} of cheapest set.".format(saved)
        print u"\t{}Grand Total: \xa3{}".format(deal_two_msg, grand_total_sets)
    print "\t", "~" * 40
```

An example for testing:

```py
import collections

types = collections.defaultdict(
    list,
    {u'car': [20.5, 25, 15], u'train': [5, 5, 5], u'tractor': [10, 10, 5]},
)
```

Comment: If you are only just learning, you should ignore Python 2, and concentrate on the supported and recommended version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: It looks like you're using both Python 2 and Python 3, just scanning over your code.

Comment: This is unclear. What is the expected output? Are the conditions not equivalent to the single rule "if you buy three of something, you get one free; the cheapest one will be free if the prices are different"? If not, how are they different? Your code looks like there are two deductions in some cases. Or do you really mean the trains should be free and on top of that you only pay for the most expensive two of each of the remaining categories?

Comment: @tripleee I have added items in the cart, I hope that explains well. the cheapest one free is for the cheapest set, for first deal the buy 3 and get 1 free.
@Linny now I have updated the OP and its just `python2.7`

Comment: Also, if you buy six of something, you should probably get two for free (otherwise you would have to buy three, walk out of the store and back in to get another three...), and so on.